# Send email when theres a change in a particular column on a particluar sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm want to use this script to send an email when a cell is changed from "**No**" to "**Yes**" in **column C** (3) from a particular sheet - **sheet1**.

Could this code be modified to do that.

```
function sendNotification(e){
if(e.range.getColumn()==3 && e.value=='YES'){
 var recipients = "***********@gmail.com";
 var subject = "Update"+e.range.getSheet().getName();
 var body = "This cell has changed";
 var valColB=e.range.getSheet().getRange(e.range.getRow(),2).getValue();
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body)
 }
}
```

Comment: Well, how are you running those functions? Note that they both attempt to access the property `range` from the variable you reference as `e`. The error clearly states that `e` is `undefined` - aka it was never initialized with a value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Comment: How do I get it to run on a particular sheet?

Comment: It looks like this question is about resolving an error, not making this script run on a sheet. Consider reviewing the place where you took this function (which should be easy - you cite code that you take from others, right?) and determine how they meant this function to be used.

Comment: Further, you haven't even said how you get it to run. Start there, by asking a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a trigger via the UI to run a sheet whenever it's edited. Conversely, you can rename your function to `onEdit(e)` and it will run whenever the sheet is edited.

Comment: It sure won't send email from a simple trigger ;)